# Spliting word between two strings in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following string

```
"summary"=>”Amazing (games) - Master"
```

I want to fetch values - v1=Amazing and v2= games.

How do I do this using ruby on rails?

Comment: See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [regular expression](http://rubular.com/r/0HzNDSMhgi) with [named captures](https://www.leighhalliday.com/named-captures-ruby-regular-expressions).

```
EXP = /^(?<v1>\w*)\s*\(\w*\)\s*-\s*(?<v2>\w*)$/.freeze
matches = value.match(EXP)
puts matches[:v1]
puts matches[:v2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to find something that is common on all of the strings that you can use as a delimeter to split the string on:

```
summary = "Amazing (games) - test"


v1, v2 = summary.split("(")

v2 = v2.split(")")[0]

puts v1
puts v2
```

Comment: but they want `v2` to equal `games`.

Answer (score 0):

Without a regex you can do

```
v1, v2 = summary.split(')').first.split('(').map(&:strip)
```